# Does Google pick and choose which rich snippets to display on their search results?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets

For example, if my website's listings properly display the breadcrumbs rich snippet, but do not show the aggregate star rating rich snippet, should I assume it is something in the structure or is Google intentionally suppressing these?

Comment: This is a good question. One way or another these questions have been asked individually, but not together which, to me, makes it more interesting. Really, there does not seem to be rhyme or reason to how Google displays breadcrumbs or ratings. Google does not guarantee anything. However, maybe through experience, someone will know something useful. Heck, there could be gold here. Who knows? Good Luck! Cheers!!

Comment: Crickets! It is either a great mystery or not a good question.

Comment: I picture Google like OZ, not just where there are thousands of munchkin PHDs making algorithms, they do the common work, but one man behind the curtain, actually two, Brin and Page. *Do not pay attention the the men behind the curtain!* Yes it is a mystery. The munchkins have no clue. They just sing in high pitched voices. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

All you have to worry about is what Google tells you.
Just use their structured data tools and fix everything what is needed to fix.
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data

If everything looks fine there, have patience. Meanwhile fix the errors you find within your search console.