# Google Search Console - Breadcrumbs

Tags: google-search-console, json-ld, breadcrumbs

Google search console enhancements breadcrumbs have stopped being picked up by the desktop crawler.

They're quite visible on pages but for some reason, search console has gradually started de-listing pages with this enhancement. The source is the desktop crawler, but perhaps by chance, this started when AMP was enabled.

No error is shown, pages have just gradually disintegrated as having this enhancement and look to be on their way right down to zero as pages are re-crawled.

Code in place is as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 1,
                "item": {
                    "@type": "WebSite",
                    "@id": "https://example.com/",
                    "name": "Home"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 2,
                    "item": {
                    "@type": "WebPage",
                    "@id": "https://example.com/category/sports-betting-services/",
                    "name": "Betting Services"
                }
            }
            ,{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 3,
                    "item": {
                    "@type": "WebPage",
                    "@id": "https://example.com/category/sports-betting-services/football/",
                    "name": "Football"                                
                }
            }
            ,{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 4,
                    "item": {
                    "@type": "WebPage",
                    "@id": "https://example.com/sports-betting-services/football/inplay-live-football-stats/",
                    "name": "Top 4 &#8211; Live Score Betting, Live Football Stats &#038; Scanners"                                
                }
            }    
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas why they're not being picked up by the crawler, the schema is present, are there aren't any visible issues with the markup? Perhaps its something to do with the site involving sports betting tips, predictions, etc or has anyone experienced this issue with AMP, gambling sites before? Or is there an issue with the schema in use?

Is there something out of place with the JSON, schema or any other visible issues with the site or it's general content or layout which may have caused this?

Comment: Somth wrong in your code, looking to https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/breadcrumb

Comment: is your breadcrumb navigation show on single AMP-pages?

Comment: It looks like they're rendering properly in AMP pages too, perhaps it was a crawler issue.

Comment: By no error is shown. Is this from a Rich Results Test set to desktop or from the URL Inspection tools results? Do both show valid breadcrumbs?

Comment: I think that the answer to this is that Google just sometimes chooses not to show breadcrumbs, even if you have valid markup.  I added a bounty to [Does Google pick and choose which rich snippets to display on their search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103298/does-google-pick-and-choose-which-rich-snippets-to-display-on-their-search-resul) in the hopes that somebody will confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Home",
    "item": "https://example.com/"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "name": "Betting Services",
    "item": "https://example.com/category/sports-betting-services/"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "name": "Football",
    "item": "https://example.com/category/sports-betting-services/football/"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 4,
    "name": "Live Football Stats",
    "item": "https://example.com/sports-betting-services/football/inplay-live-football-stats/"
  }]
}
```